# casting multiple columns astype

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Should be an easy to answer question... Am I doing this wrong? Can I not cast multiple columns?

```
>>> val results2 = results.select( results["HCAHPS Base Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Base Score"]), results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"]) )
File "<stdin>", line 1
val results2 = results.select( results["HCAHPS Base Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Base Score"]), results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"]) )
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The syntax error keeps popping up right around the comma...

Comment: why ``val`` use only ``results2 = results.select( results["HCAHPS Base Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Base Score"]), results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"].cast(IntegerType).as(results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"]) )``

Comment: still getting syntax error, this time right after first quote mark here near the end: results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"])

Comment: what is error now?

Comment: and don't use ``results["HCAHPS Base Score"])`` instead use ``from pyspark.sql.functions import col`` and then change your statement to ``results2 = results.select( col("HCAHPS Base Score").cast(IntegerType), col("HCAHPS Consistency Score").cast(IntegerType))``

Comment: is this solved?

Comment: yes but my stringtype columns had quotes wrapping them so integer conversion resulted in null values everywhere. Could you help me with my revised code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659944/syntaxerror-defining-schema-for-sparksql-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I assume this is pySpark as the question is tagged under `PySpark`

```
results2 = results.select( results["HCAHPS Base Score"].cast(IntegerType()).alias("HCAHPS Base Score"), results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"].cast(IntegerType()).alias("HCAHPS Consistency Score") )
```

In Scala, you may try the below.

```
val results2 = results.select( results["HCAHPS Base Score"].cast(IntegerType).as("HCAHPS Base Score"), results["HCAHPS Consistency Score"].cast(IntegerType).as("HCAHPS Consistency Score") )
```